# How to special HTTP request source IP in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I use the selenium to open the google.com:

```
from selenium import webdriver

wd = webdriver.Chrome(r"/opt/webdrivers/chromedriver")

wd.implicitly_wait(5)

wd.get("https://www.google.com")
```

but I have a requirement, in my Server I have several IPs, I want to special a IP to execute this code. how?

I seached google, but only get the `proxy setting` param, not special the source IP:

```
optoins.add_argument('--proxy-server=http:x.x.x.x:port')
```

Comment: Hi, given an IP is a numeric network identifier, there are a number of different underlying IP addresses that could be involved here. Could you clarify if you want to 1) send the request from google through a certain local network interface, or 2) want to access a particular google IP which www.google.com resolves to using DNS, or 3) want to use a particular network proxy to send the traffic through, or 4) something else? You might need to share a bit more on the goal as well. Eg, is there a particular reason it should be google, or is another website ok?

Comment: Is this you want? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155446/linux-is-there-handy-way-to-exec-a-program-binding-it-to-ip-address-of-choice